# How to authenticate REST API request when using service account credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vertex-ai-search

I am trying to use the REST API to get search results for an app with unstructured data, using the `servingConfigs.search` method from the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/preview-search-results#genappbuilder_search-rest).

I am using the service account key as the `'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'` environment variable, however in the header of the REST request it requires an access token. Simply using

```
shell_exec(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
```

I cannot get the access token.

When i manually run the command i can generate the access token and the authorisation works. However using `shell_exec()` to run the `gcloud` commands returns null.

Is there a different library or something i can use to get this access token?

I tried to generate an access token to authorise the REST request, however it only works when i manually generate the token via CLI. I have tried using relative and absolute paths for the `gcloud` command but neither give me the result i expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for how to handle authentication in a local development environment.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-dev

Based on your use of the `exec_shell()` function, it seems like you're using PHP for your application.

The Google Cloud PHP Client Library repository shows how to authenticate using a local service account JSON file.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/main/AUTHENTICATION.md

And here is the Code Sample for the PHP Client Library of Vertex AI Search

https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/preview-search-results#genappbuilder_search-php